# Tracking checkbox event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$("#chkbx_first").change(function () {
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    alert("Check Box Selected"); //do something when checked
} else {
    alert("Check Box Unselected"); //do something when cleared
}
```

The problem is that despite on the checkbox stste the second allert appears all the time - "Check Box Unselected". Why the first alert doesn't appear ?

Is there another approaches to track the CHECK event? 
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if (this.checked)` or Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#chkbx_first").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) { // or if($(this).prop("checked")){
        alert("Check Box Selected"); //do something when checked
    } else {
        alert("Check Box Unselected"); //do something when cleared
    }
}
```

Read [Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName)

Comment: I got the message - "'this' souldn't be used in the global context"

Comment: @AndreyLangovoy than use `if($(this).prop("checked")){` n make na fiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).attr("checked");
```

will [`not work with from jQuery 1.6.`](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6)

Instead use

jquery [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
$(this).prop("checked");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/d663m/)**

or

jquery [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/d663m/1/)**

or

```
this.checked
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/d663m/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Checked is a property not an attribute of a checkbox, use `.prop()` instead

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

You could use alse the native DOM (faster)

```
this.checked
```